# Displaying the largest 'n' items from a data set in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: Sample Problem]

I have a data table that contains the Sales Rep, Customer Name, and Sales Amount information. And there are 2 summary tables as shown in the image above.

Which formula can be used to update each sales rep's top 3 customer name and amounts? The goal is to pick up the largest three sales for a given time period and display them as shown above. The ideal solution works in Excel 2013 and does not require VBA, pivot tablesor additional plugins, i.e it is formula based.

Thanks!

Comment: You should seriously look into Pivot Tables, which does _not_ require the use of VBA or any additional plugins.  You are basically looking to do the equivalent of a `GROUP BY` in SQL followed by a summary.  Pivot Tables is perfect for this use case.

Comment: How do you want to handle ties? If there is a tie for 3rd, choose the first one that appears in the list?

Comment: Thanks Tim, I know this could be solved with pivot tables but I am looking for a formula only solution. A formula based solution will scale better with the actual data I need to apply this to.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both formulas you are going to need to press **CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER**.

Also, enter the formula for the amount table first because this table is referenced in the formula for the customers table.

Enter this formula for the Amount in cell I3 and copy across and down:

```
=IFERROR(LARGE(IF($A$3:$A$29=$H3,$C$3:$C$29),COLUMNS($A:A)),"")
```

And then this formula for the Customers in cell E3 and copy across and down :

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(SMALL(IF($D3=$A$3:$A$29,IF(I3=$C$3:$C$29,ROW($A$3:$A$29)-ROW($A$3)+1)),COUNTIF($I3:I3,I3)),ROW($A$3:$A$29)-ROW($A$3)+1,$B$3:$B$29),"")
```

Two things to point out:

1. The formula for the Customer's table takes into account ties (Which is why it needs to reference the Amount table). If there is a tie for third, the customer that appears in the list first will be chosen.
2. I wrapped both formulas with an IFERROR function to take into account that a sales rep may only have two customers (See Janice in my example below). If this is the case, the cell for their #3 customer will return "".

Use this image to help line up the formulas:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

These formulas would return Janice's top 3 **amounts** (assuming names are in `A1:A7` and amounts are in `B1:B7`)

```
=LARGE(IF(A1:A7="Janice",B1:B7,0),1)
=LARGE(IF(A1:A7="Janice",B1:B7,0),2)
=LARGE(IF(A1:A7="Janice",B1:B7,0),3)
```

You'd need to enter them as array formulas, meaning you type them in and press `Ctrl+Enter`.

Comment: You can make it one formula by changing the last parameter in the LARGE function to COLUMNS($A:A).